# How to remove b from the beginning of each line of string read from file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading a csv as follows.

```
data = pd.read_csv('news.csv')
```

It contains `news` and `category` as columns. I need to tokenize the words in news column.
The problem is that each line of text in news column contains `b` at the beginning.

> b'Longevity Increase Seen Around the World: WHO'
> b'Chikungunya spreading, mosquito-borne virus ...

I tried [How do I get rid of the b-prefix in a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) but this is for byte encoded string. So,

```
line = data['news'][0]
line.decode('utf-8')
```

would cause:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Each of those lines are of type `str`. How do I remove those b's ?

Comment: hi ..maybe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923189/remove-first-character-from-pandas-column-if-the-number-1

Comment: If you don't know what the original encoding was `line[2:-1]` should look ok for most letters. If you know it was utf-8 `line[2:-1].encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")` should work.

Comment: If the b prefix is already visible in the csv file itself then the file is being generated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This `b''` may point to byte type that could be decoded to string `''`, but also could be a string itself with content `b'...'`.

For the first case you need `line.decode()`, the second case need `line[2:-1]`.